# Access IE Popup Window form from VBA Excel Script

Tags: excel, vba

A colleague sent me a VBA script that runs within Microsoft Excel that, from my perspective (as someone who has never written VBA code before), appears to do a few relatively simple things:

- Open up Internet Explorer, and navigate to a specific page
- Fill out a few HTML form elements in that page using cells from the Excel Spreadsheet
- Fire off a Javascript routine to popup a new window
- Fill out a few fields on that popup window
- Submit the form on the popup window

This is the code they wrote that's supposed to do that:

```
Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "https://myurl.com/mylandingpage"
    IE.Visible = True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))
    IE.Document.All("name").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("t2")
    IE.Document.All("address").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("w2")
    IE.Document.All("phone_number").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("x2")
    IE.Navigate "javascript:helpModLvl('/mylandingpage/popup_window','pop_up_form')"
    Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "pop_up_form")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    IE.Document.All("id").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("H2")
    IE.Document.All("new_address").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("I2")
    IE.Document.All("submit").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
End Sub
```

For the sake of argument, assume that the landing page does have fields named `name`, `address`, and `phone_number`, and that the popup window has fields `id`, `new_address`, and `submit`, the latter of which is a proper button.

My concern is that even though they query for the popup window, they never actually use it (note that `Ret` is never used again after it gets assigned, and as a result, the later calls to set values for `id`, and so on, never actually manifest, because they're still iterating on the original webpage.

Is my understanding of this code correct? Should calls after the popup window is created be based on the handle `Ret`, or should I expect the code to be correct as-is?

Comment: There is a new navigation in there  so in theory , if valid, you are now working with the new ie document but I have to say that IE.Navigate "javascript:helpModLvl('/mylandingpage/popup_window','pop_up_form')"  is odd looking. And yes, nothing is done with the FindWindow part so appears redundant within context of code shown. I can't see how  IE.Navigate "javascript:helpModLvl('/mylandingpage/popup_window','pop_up_form')" would be valid as the script is not executed. Does this even run?

Comment: Rather than just the explicit Waits there should be   While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend lines to allow for page loading after each navigation and any click events.  Then potentially a timed loop to find elements and/or explicit waits if required for slow loading/dynamic pages. I would expect a loop to find the window handle's window if needing to switch windows, otherwise a clear URL being used for the new navigation step (in which case you don't need window handle).